# How to correctly put URL into jQuery load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is, from `example.com/page1`, to load text of an ID from homepage `example.com` into class `class`.

What I've tried:

```
 $('.class').load('example.com #ID');
```

But what this does is try to load from `example.com/page1/example.com` instead of just `example.com`

I've also tried:

```
     var urltoload = 'https://example.com/';
     $('.class').load(urltoload, '#ID');
```

which *does* load content but loads the **entire page!** instead of just the content from the example.com ID.

Then there's also the fact that I still haven't guessed the syntax for getting just the *text* from that ID. Maybe something like  `$('.class').load(urltoload, $('#ID').text());` ?

Thank you for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works for me:

Html:

```
    <div class="class"></div>
     <input id="id" value="3"/>
```

Script:

```
  $(".class").html('<object data="http://validator.w3.org?id="+$("#id").val()/>');
```

Comment: I 'm happy to hear that .Good luck my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

**GET:**

```
$('.class').load("template.html?Id = VALUE_TO_PASS");
```

**POST:**

```
$('.class').load("template.html",{Id = VALUE_TO_PASS});
```

Comment: For whatever reason that doesn't work for me.  The class version would be `$('.class').load("template.html?Class = VALUE_TO_PASS");` right? Anyway either one doesn't work and I've tried with and without quotation marks. It just says 'unrecognized expression'. Is the URL part maybe supposed to be written out fully like `example.com/page1.html`? I'm struggling here.

Comment: Also, do you know how to target the Text of that ID?

Comment: My friend I sent my example code below. I hope that would help you